# Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl

I am trying to execute one stored procedure using 'sa' user through perl script

save this line in a perl file and execute that perl file

```
system("start /wait sqlcmd.exe -S serverName -U sa -P test@123 -d JSONdb -Q \"EXECUTE UPDATE_SP\" -o C:\\Temp\\log.txt");
```

=============================================================================

> -S serverName :: sql server which i want to connect.
>
> -U sa -P test@123 :: login user credentials
>
> -d JSONdb :: database name.
>
> \"EXECUTE update_JSONTable\" :: command to execute stored procedure
>   [update_JSONTable]
>
> -o C:\Temp\log.txt" :: saving  logs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are can be three reasons:

1. SQL Server (or mixed) authentication is disabled
2. The password used in the command is wrong
3. The database `[JSONdb]` is not available

Another reason can be related to special characters escaping. Your password contains <kbd>@</kbd>, therefore this argument is to be also adjusted:

```
 -P test@123 =>  -P test\@123
```

Comment: checked all this points all are correct in data base. still getting same issue.

Comment: @jit, and you can log in to that server using SSMS and exactly the same credentials?

Comment: and   yes i can login through SSMS by using credentials which i have. but when i run through perl script it failed

Comment: then the problem is in password and seems it it is becasue of  character "@". I've updated the answer